# Backup Bluestacks

Tags: backup, windows, bluestacks

How do I backup Bluestacks on one Windows PC to move the install to another while maintaining all installed apps and saved data?

Seems like a simple procedure but I've not found a solution that does not involve installing an app and backing up one app at a time inside of Bluestacks. This would be very time consuming and impractical.

The data for Bluestacks seems to be in C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks, is it enough to back this up and replace this folder on the destination PC with the folder from the source PC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, yes it should backup the apps and its data. I've tried moving bluestacks setup files under (`C:\ProgramData\BlueStacksSetup`) with just copying and moving to another computer but it only moves Bluestacks's setup files from one pc to another. And the Bluestacks will have only preinstalled apps not the apps you have installed in the previous computer. So you'll get just the bluestacks software skipping the initial `Downloading game data` screen so its a big time saver. And the apps and appdata are stored in another location `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks`.

So try copying and moving the files under both the below,

- `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacks` - Contains Android and Apps related data
- `C:\ProgramData\BlueStacksSetup` - Contains BlueStacks setup data directories and hopefully it should work.