# Manually backup and restore individual Bluestacks instances?

Tags: backup, restore, bluestacks

I am looking to see if anyone has successfully figured out a way to manually backup and restore Bluestacks instances.  I am not asking about Bluestacks backup and restore capability as this does not do individual instances - it's all or nothing - individual instances are not currently supported.

However, regardless of supportability, I have a need to migrate some instances across computers.  There are a few configuration items that would have to be addressed:

1. port number conflict potential
2. `bluestacks.conf` changes
3. potential change in directory at target

I was wondering if anyone has attempted to execute this effort and whether you've been successful.  Am I missing anything else that could be dependent?

Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. There's a similar Q&A: [Backup Bluestacks](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/110937/44325), does it help?

Comment: It does not help but thank you.  As mentioned, I want to cherry pick the instances to move to and from PCs.  BS method is only all or none approach.